# What's the difference between two kernel version shown by ‘uname -a’?

Tags: gdb, debian, kernel, crash-dumps, uname

I am using debian 9.4, the kernel version shown by `uname -a` is different, what's the actual kernel version? What does '4.9.82-1+deb9u3' mean?

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`apt-get source linux` can get the source code of current kernel, then I can get original kernel tar file and debian patch.

```
$ls     
linux-4.9.82                         linux_4.9.82-1+deb9u3.dsc
linux_4.9.82-1+deb9u3.debian.tar.xz  linux_4.9.82.orig.tar.xz
```

`linux_4.9.82-1+deb9u3.debian.tar.xz` contains many files, what are them used for? how to patch the it to `linux_4.9.82.orig.tar.xz` ?

`linux-4.9.82` is the kernel source folder outputted by `apt-get source` command, which can be compiled to vmlinux. However, I usually can't debug the crash dump files with the vmlinux, as 'crash' command gives the error message: mismatch version.  Should I download `kernel 4.9.0` from kernel.org  instead of `linux-4.9.82` to debug my current running kernel ?

Answer (score 3):

You have the package version. The name is made by:

- `4.9.82`: the upstream version
- `-1`: separator and Debian version of `4.9.82` upstream package. Note: if Debian is also upstream of a package, this field is skipped.
- `+deb9u3`: this is a sort of micro-version. The `+deb` is used for security advisories, so minimal changes compared with `4.9.82-1`. The `9` is the Debian version, and `u3` is the third security version.

But kernels are different (compared with most of other packages): one could install many in parallel (but it will use only one). So in the package name you may have `linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64`. In my system this package has version `4.9.30-2+deb9u1`. So `4.9` is the kernel version. `-amd64` is the architecture, this is the third major Debian version (`-3`) of `4.9`(`.0`) series, which is based on `4.9.30`.

the command `uname` will give you the kernel (as package name, so near the capability) in the field `kernel-release` and the package version (so exact reference to source) in the field `kernel-version`).

For the main question: I would use original kernel, and compile with upstream method (if I think the bug is kernel related, so it is easier to discuss with kernel maintainers), or I would use Debian sources (e.v. with patch), and build the kernel with Debian tools (and install the package to install the kernel), if I think the problem is in Debian, or just on old kernel versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So you mean 4.9.82 is the original real kernel version obtained from kernel.org in my system ?  @Giacomo Catenazzi